# Can we have XIB for UITableViewCell with dynamic height?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a `TableView` with `custom TableView cell` with `multiple XIB` one for `Image`, other for `Text + Video`. But the height has to be predefined for the XIB in the interface.

So how can I have an XIB for my UITableViewCell with `dynamic height`?

Comment: you need to specify height in UITableView Delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @PiyushRathi It's no longer needed since iOS 8.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your `viewDidLoad`:

`yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = yourTableViewCellHeight
 yourTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: @lokeshguddu Please flag this answer as the correct answer for this thread to "close" the discussion, thank you.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano How should I do that? I don't see the option to do that.

Comment: @lokeshguddu The V flag to the left of the answer

Comment: @lokeshguddu I'm glad it can help :-)